# Horizontal Navbar Issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I'm working on a portfolio site and need some help getting my navbar to work horizontally. I'm adapting a vertical navbar I created recently for another site but I'm struggling to get it horizontal, and especially struggling to get the drop-down menu to expand vertically and actually drop-down below the navbar as opposed to expanding out to the left as it is currently.

I will attach my code and a fiddle below.

HTML:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Work</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>Commercial</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Residential</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#cssmenu {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li.active > ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

.align-right {
  float: left;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 26px;
  top: 19px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 2px;
  background: #000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}

#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  top: 23px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}

#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub.open > a:after,
#cssmenu ul > li.has-sub.open > a:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  padding: 14px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}

#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 32px;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  top: 16px;
  right: 26px;
  background: #000;
}

#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  top: 20px;
  background: #000;
}
```

And the fiddle can be seen here - http://jsfiddle.net/yw9j1dow/1/

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some positioning: here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yw9j1dow/2/

I've added this css:

```
#cssmenu ul li ul li {display: block; float: left;}
#cssmenu ul.sub-menu {position: absolute; top: 100%;}
```

And also this class to the sub nav in the html:

```
 <ul class="sub-menu">
```

The issue was that your sub nav was inheriting the `display: inline-block` that you set earlier in your styles. You also need the `absolute` positioning to get the list to flow downwards properly.